# IOS Quartz2D cannot get image from current context

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-2d

What am I missing? Been stuck for several hours, drawRect draws as expected, getTheImage() is called from a viewcontoller UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() returns nil; tried many variations.
Any help is appreciated.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor    blackColor]CGColor]);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context,100.0,100.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,200.0,200.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context,200.0,200.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,200.0,400.0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}


-(UIImage *)getTheImage
{
    UIImage *drawImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    NSLog(@"drawImage %@",drawImage);
    return drawImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should call this function only when a bitmap-based graphics context is the current graphics context. If the current context is nil or was not created by a call to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, this function returns nil.

appearantly your call is not in a context.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
-(UIImage *)getTheImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *drawImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSLog(@"drawImage %@",drawImage);
    return drawImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, still not working UIGraphicsBeginImageContext only takes 1 argument.

Comment: changed UIGraphicsBeginImageContext to UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions, still no go

Comment: Sorry regarding UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions. Can you tell me from where are you calling this getTheImage method? I called this method from viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear method of view controller and from both the places image is not coming nil.
However when I called this method from viewDidLoad, image is coming nil.

You should call getTheImage method only after the view is loaded completely.

Comment: hi Pranav, I am calling getTheImage() when a button is pushed, to save it in documents directory.

Comment: For me, the above code snippet which I posted is working. I checked this by calling this code on tap of a button.Then also it is working.Can you post some more details?

Comment: thanks Pranav, I will reorganize my code and retry your snippet, will let you how it goes.